# what neural network model is the most effective

Tags: yolo, faster-rcnn

at the moment I study neural network. I tried to use different models to recognize people and came across one very interesting question for me. I used yolo v3, mask r-cnn, but all of them in the photos taken from an indirect angle missed people in the photo. Which of the existing models is the most accurate and effective ?

Answer (score 0):

This is the main problem with deep learning models. For every instance of an object you want to detect, there should be at least one similar object to it (in case of angle, size, color, shape, etc) in the training set. The more similar objects in the training data, the higher probability of the object to be detected.

In case of speed and accuracy, **YOLO V3** is currently one of the best. **Mask RCNN** is also one of the best models if you want the exact boundaries of the object (segmentation). If there is no need for the exact boundaries of the objects, I would recommend using YOLO for its efficiency, You can work on your training data and try to add multiple instances of people with different sizes, angles, shapes, and also include cases of truncation and occlusion (when just parts of a person is visible) to get more generalization in the model's performance.